# Нужно ли брать в кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Фраза такая:

> Предложение использует словосочетание с глаголом «лечить».

Нужно ли заключать в кавычки слово?

Answer (score 1):

Если в тексте встречается словосочетание такого вида, то нужно использовать кавычки или выделить слово курсивом: **глагол "лечить", глагол *лечить*.**

В этом случае слово *глагол* является приложением к слову *лечить*, и это нужно обозначить.

Answer (score 1):

Да, у вас написано верно. Здесь речь идет не о самом процессе лечения, а о некоем глаголе, этот процесс обозначающем. Это своего рода название, близкое по функции к имени собственному.
Кавычки необходимы.

Впрочем, как верно уже заметили, в некоторых случаях кавычки заменяют стилевым выделением (курсивом чаще всего). Это делается в тех случаях, когда обилие кавычек создало бы нежелательную простоту. В вашем тексте такое выглядит вполне возможным.